# how to get user email in facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am use facebook graph api for Login with Facebook account.
My graph api version is 2.12.
The problem is i can't get user email, my code is like this

```
$dialog_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' . FACEBOOK_APP_ID . '&redirect_uri=' . $callback_url;
```

//token access

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token='.$access_token;
```

But i only get id and name not email, i don't know why, somebody helps me.

Comment: may be that is the problem, can u tell me how to ask email permission? something like this? $dialog_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' . FACEBOOK_APP_ID . '&redirect_uri=' . $callback_url . '&scope=email';

Comment: yes. see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to authorize users with the `email` permission:

```
$dialog_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' . FACEBOOK_APP_ID . '&redirect_uri=' . $callback_url . '&scope=email';
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: you are welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer.